# php get second element of xml tree

Tags: php, xml

I have xml file:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <lala id="1" val="2" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <lala id="11" val="22" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <lala id="111" val="222" />
    </item>
</root>
```

How I can get first (or second) item?

I try

```
$index = 2;     
$x = $xml->xpath("/root/item[$index]/lala");

//$x - this is SimpleXMLElement
```

but this code not working

Thanks!

Comment: What output *exactly* are you expecting.  "not working" as a general rule makes it hard to understand what you want.  For instance, I'm not sure if you're expecting `<lala id="11" val="22">` or `22`, or some other value to be assigned to `$x`

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXmlElement::xpath()` returns an array of matched elements. Even if your expression returns a single element, it will be in an array:

```
$index = 2;     
$elements = $xml->xpath("/root/item[$index]/lala");
$x = $elements[0];
```